# Google Map with Bottom Navigation in android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, bottomnavigationview

I'm developing Android Google Map project in Android Studio. I have a MapActivtity to show location(The Blew Code:)

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private LatLng marker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng iran = new LatLng(29, 52);

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(iran, 5.0f));

    addMarker(29.1,52.2,"ssss");
}


public void addMarker(double Lat,Double Lng, String Title){
    marker=new LatLng(Lat,Lng);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker).title(Title));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker, 10.0f));
    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(marker));

}
```

And my layout is like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

when the App run, Map Show Correctly, But I want to show Map like below image with bottom navigation. when the map button select, The map show.
[image: this]

Comment: what's the problem with current code ?

Comment: How can I add bottom navigation to this code???

Comment: Have you tried adding that ?

Comment: I tried, and create a bottom navigation layout and class(main activity), but I don't know how to link classes(mapactivity and main activity) to show map in a bottom navigation button.

Comment: instead of activity move your map code to a fragment

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: search about maps in fragment and you will get the way to start